Ubuntu stopped booting, blank screen
HP laptop has worked great for 2 years. I shut it down, went away for a week, came home…. And now it won’t boot properly.
Blank screen, briefly displays bios errors:
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Attempt to Createfield of length zero ….(see pic)
…then blank screen again.
Reboot, pressing shift, I am able to get to safe mode…. But every restart leads back to blank screen.  Please help, I’m not very Linux OR CMD line savvy.
HP with AMD silver 3050u Radeon graphics
Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
EDIT:  I can load everything fine if I select earlier generic kernel 5.15.0-107. (5.15.0-113 generic leads to blank screen)  But every restart still leads to problem above if I don’t enter GRUB and select old kernel.  How can I fix this?


Just have grub remember the last kernel you booted with and keep using it automatically. You can google that.
